Can I replace the cartridge in my shower valve to restore smooth operation?
Want to replace my shower valve that doesn't operate smoothly. Is there a quick DIY solution, i.e. without replacing the entire unit? Is just the cartridge replaceable?


What research have you done? Have you searched here for "valve replacement" where there are dozens, if not hundreds of questions asking about how to do exactly what you're asking?

Normally yes. And normally that solves most issues. You do have to identify the thing, which for some reason seems to be made excessively annoying by the manufacturers (cast or stamp a name and model number in the <bleeping> thing? Oh, no, we couldn't do THAT!)
Since this appears to have the built-in shutoffs, you should be able to shut them off, remove the cartridge, and take it to a plumbing supply  (or take pictures to the internet) to identify the thing and get a matching replacement.
Might want to fix the slow leak on the secondary (possibly anti-scald section as a separate unit) cover that's turning it blue with corrosion.
This (lower one on the page with the screwdriver shutoffs, described as "stop/check valve kit") might be your valve? Hmm, similar, but probably not an exact match, looking more closely. Or is that the angle of the illustration? An-Noy-Ing, they are.
https://assets.moen.com/shared/docs/exploded-parts-views/3510pt.pdf
In which case the corroding bit is the end of the "balancing spool." Probably should replace both. If you've owned the house since it went in, parts might be free from Moen, though I'm not sure if they require the probably long-lost original receipt...

I would for sure try to clean this out before replacing.    If the rings aren't rotten or broke you have a 90% chance of using it again.
